# SWIFT: Map - Location issue

Tags: mapkit, cllocation, coordinate

I'm new to Swift and write an app to show my locally saved locations on a map. In one ViewController I save the locations

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
    didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!)
{
    var latestLocation: AnyObject = locations[locations.count - 1]

    latitudeLabel.text = String(format: "%.4f",
        latestLocation.coordinate.latitude)
    longitudeLabel.text = String(format: "%.4f",
        latestLocation.coordinate.longitude)
```

In an other ViewController I try to show it on the map but since in the second I had to import the MapKit, in the first ViewController appeared an error.

```
import MapKit
```

class MapViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!


// set initial location in Honolulu
let initialLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 21.282778, longitude: -157.829444)

let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 1000
func centerMapOnLocation(location: CLLocation) {
    let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate,
        regionRadius * 2.0, regionRadius * 2.0)
    mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

I know that the coordinates are no longer supported by the MapKit and instead of AnyObject I should use but I don't know how exactly should I change the locationManager code. :(

Hope someone can help.

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: Thank you for your question. Meanwhile I solved the problem.